# MY_PERMISSONS_REQUEST not defined?

Tags: android, android-permissions

I am attempting to check for permission for an app and am currently following the Android Developers training.
However, I encountered a problem when plugging in the code set forth in the [page](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html).

The page claims that MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST is an app defined int constant. However, when I put it in my actual app, it said that it wasn't defined...

Can someone show an explanation why this is the case?
Thanks!

Example code:

```
// Here, thisActivity is the current activity
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(thisActivity,
                Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS)
        != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

    // Should we show an explanation?
    if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(thisActivity,
            Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS)) {

        // Show an expanation to the user *asynchronously* -- don't block
        // this thread waiting for the user's response! After the user
        // sees the explanation, try again to request the permission.

    } else {

        // No explanation needed, we can request the permission.

        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(thisActivity,
                new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS},
                MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS);

        // MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS is an
        // app-defined int constant. The callback method gets the
        // result of the request.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may just define it as a field constant, like this:

```
private static final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS = 1;

// Here, thisActivity is the current activity
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(thisActivity,
                Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS)
        != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    ...
```

This is because there may be other requests. You can distinguish it from others by the request code you defined.

Comment: So... it's just a normal constant? It says that it's already App Defined?

Comment: @MinusReputation *App defined* means your app defines. That is you define the constant. Not by the Android SDK.